# Overflow hidden for custom-shaped images

Tags: css, css-animations

Here's the 2 image layers:

[image]

The hand with phone and a black hole.

HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="wrapper__image" src="path/to/image.png">
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background: url("path/to/blackhole.png") no-repeat center bottom;
  width: 528px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;

  &__image {
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the hand image with a phone is a bit rounded at the bottom, also a blackhole is rounded, so if i push the hand beyond the `wrapper` div, there would be spaces on the hand's image at the bottom.

Is there a way to push the hand image below the black hole and hide it, without transparent corners on the black hole image:

[image]

if the black hole was a square shape, then there would be no problems.

My purpose is to hide a hand with the phone in a black hole, just like it sliding down in the hole.

Comment: Clip path - just saying!

Comment: clip-path is not widely supported in a browsers, plus it would work if i have a static image, but i'm sliding down the image with animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the hole using pure CSS and you will be able to obtain the needed effect.

Hover to see the effect. You simply need to adjust the coloration to make it look like your image.

```css
.hole {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50px;
}

.hole::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, grey, black);
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100px;
  transition:2s all;
}
.hole:hover img {
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hole">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200?image=1069">
</div>
```

Comment: O, nice, going to try it out. Positioning is required here?

Comment: @AlexanderKim for the image, it's not required, it's simply easy to create the animation with it

Comment: It works, thanks. I dunno, but i thought making a hole with css is not going to work. You're a CSS guru, definitely, lol